# TouchOpacity onPress request is not working with formik and react-native-text-input-mask

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, formik, yup

When i tried to login the button is not sending request. On button pree i supposed to console the output. It seems that the onChangeText and onChange is not working correcttly in TextInputMask.
**TouchableOpacity tag has onPress event where onPress={()=>formikProps.handleSubmit()} is not triggering the onSubmit props of formik.**
Here i'm using yup for validation and Formik for submitting data.

```
    const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  phoneNumber: yup
    .string()
    .label("Phone Number")

    .required("Phone Number is required."),
  password: yup.string().label("Password").required("Password is required."),
});
class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      username: "",
      password: "",
      press: false,
      ButtonStateHolder: false,
    };
  }
render() {
    return (
      <ImageBackground style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }} source={bgImg}>
        <ScrollView>         
          <Formik
            initialValues={{ phoneNumber: "", password: "" }}
            onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
              this.setState({
                password: values.password,
                ButtonStateHolder: true,
              });
              console.warn(this.state.phoneNumber);
              console.warn(this.state.password);

            }}
            validationSchema={validationSchema}
          >
            {(formikProps) => (
              <React.Fragment>
                <View>
                  <View>
                    <Text>Phone number</Text>
                    <TextInputMask
                      keyboardType="number-pad"
                      ref={(ref) => (this.phoneField = ref)}
                      onChangeText={(formatted, extracted) => {                        
                        this.setState({
                          phoneNumber: extracted,
                        });
                      }}
                      onChange={formikProps.handleChange("phoneNumber")}
                      onBlur={formikProps.handleBlur("phoneNumber")}
                      placeholder={""}
                      mask={"([000]) [000] [0000]"}
                    />
                    <Text style={styles.errMsg}>
                      {formikProps.touched.phoneNumber &&
                        formikProps.errors.phoneNumber}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                  <View>
                    <Text style={styles.formLable}>Password</Text>
                    <TextInput
                      onChangeText={formikProps.handleChange("password")}
                      onBlur={formikProps.handleBlur("password")}
                      placeholder={""}
                      returnKeyType={"done"}
                      autoCapitalize={"none"}
                      autoCorrect={false}
                    />
                    <Text style={styles.errMsg}>
                      {formikProps.touched.password &&
                        formikProps.errors.password}
                    </Text>
                    
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      activeOpacity={0.7}
                      style={styles.btnEye}
                      onPress={this.showPass}
                    >
                      <Image source={eyeImg} style={styles.iconEye} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.loginBottom}>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.button}
                    onPress={() => formikProps.handleSubmit()}
                  >
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}> Login </Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                
                </View>
              </React.Fragment>
            )}
          </Formik>
        </ScrollView>
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

onPress console log is not printed
Someone please help to solve this issue

Comment: I don't see any console.log

Comment: Which onPress are you talking about ?

Comment: @HichamELBSI You can see onPress event in TouchOpacity tag where onPress={() => formikprops.handleSubmit()} and in onSubmit handler of formikProps i set the current state to new state. Then i console.warn() the state.

Comment: Thanks @HichamELBSI for ur response. If u know the way to solve this issue please discuss here

Answer (score 0):

Formik will manage the state of inputs for you so you don't need to declare it.

```js
const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  phoneNumber: yup
    .string()
    .label("Phone Number")

    .required("Phone Number is required."),
  password: yup.string().label("Password").required("Password is required."),
});

class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <ScrollView>         
          <Formik
            initialValues={{ phoneNumber: "", password: "" }}
            onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
              alert(JSON.stringify(values));
            }}
            validationSchema={validationSchema}
          >
            {({handleChange, values, handleSubmit, touched, errors, handleBlur}) => (
              <React.Fragment>
                <View>
                  <View>
                    <Text>Phone number</Text>
                    <TextInput
                      keyboardType="number-pad"
                      onChangeText={handleChange}
                      onChange={handleChange("phoneNumber")}
                      onBlur={handleBlur("phoneNumber")}
                      placeholder={""}
                      mask={"([000]) [000] [0000]"}
                      value={values.phoneNumber}
                    />
                    <Text>
                      {touched.phoneNumber &&
                        errors.phoneNumber}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                  <View>
                    <Text>Password</Text>
                    <TextInput
                      onChangeText={handleChange("password")}
                      onBlur={handleBlur("password")}
                      placeholder={""}
                      returnKeyType={"done"}
                      autoCapitalize={"none"}
                      autoCorrect={false}
                      value={values.password}
                    />
                    <Text>
                      {touched.password &&
                        errors.password}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                </View>
                <View >
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => handleSubmit()}
                  >
                    <Text> Login </Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                
                </View>
              </React.Fragment>
            )}
          </Formik>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

You can also manage the form with the `useFormik` hook instead of the `Formik` component

```js
import { useFormik } from 'formik';

const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  phoneNumber: yup
    .string()
    .label("Phone Number")

    .required("Phone Number is required."),
  password: yup.string().label("Password").required("Password is required."),
});

const Home = () => {
    const { handleChange, values, handleSubmit, touched, errors, handleBlur } = useFormik({
      initialValues: {
         phoneNumber: "", password: ""
      },
      onSubmit: (values, actions) => {
         alert(JSON.stringify(values));
      },
      validationSchema
    });

    console.log(values);
    
    return (
      <View>
        <ScrollView>
                <View>
                  <View>
                    <Text>Phone number</Text>
                    <TextInput
                      keyboardType="number-pad"
                      onChangeText={handleChange}
                      onChange={handleChange("phoneNumber")}
                      onBlur={handleBlur("phoneNumber")}
                      placeholder={""}
                      mask={"([000]) [000] [0000]"}
                      value={values.phoneNumber}
                    />
                    <Text>
                      {touched.phoneNumber &&
                        errors.phoneNumber}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                  <View>
                    <Text>Password</Text>
                    <TextInput
                      onChangeText={handleChange("password")}
                      onBlur={handleBlur("password")}
                      placeholder={""}
                      returnKeyType={"done"}
                      autoCapitalize={"none"}
                      autoCorrect={false}
                      value={values.password}
                    />
                    <Text>
                      {touched.password &&
                        errors.password}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                </View>
                <View >
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => handleSubmit()}
                  >
                    <Text> Login </Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>

                </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Let me know if I misunderstood something or if it helps you

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I need those data to be use inside my component. So, if i don't declare state inside my component will formik manage data inside component also like we manage data inside component using state?

Comment: You can use the useFormik with a functional component instead. Check out my edited answer.